# Database values getting cleared after exiting service

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have created a service which is invoked by alarm manager every 5 secs.My service uses methods from dbHandler class to add, update, check for updated info and check for availability of data in database. After inserting data into the table when my service is invoked again next time it still gets no result and same data is again.Log of service checking and adding data:

dbHandler onCreate:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + tableN + "(" +
            column_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            column_name + " TEXT ," +
            column_desc + " TEXT ," +
            column_activity + " TEXT ," +
            column_contact + " TEXT " +

            ");";
    db.execSQL(query);

}
```

methods for checking and adding data to database

```
public void add_n(nDatabse tuple) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(column_id, tuple.get_id());
    values.put(column_name, tuple.get_name());
    values.put(column_desc, tuple.get_description());
    values.put(column_activity, tuple.get_activity());
    values.put(column_contact, tuple.get_contact());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();



    //Inserting in Database

    db.insert(tableN, null, values);

    //checking Entry of Database
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableN + " WHERE " + column_id + " = " + tuple.get_id() + " ";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        Log.d( " After Adding Data...",c.getString(1));}

    db.close();
}
```

For Checking Availability

```
public boolean checkNotAvailable(nDatabse tuple) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableN + " WHERE " + column_id + " = " + tuple.get_id() + " ";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    //Log.d("as",toString().valueOf(tuple.get_id()));
    if (c.getCount() == 0) {
        Log.d("NO ENTRY", toString().valueOf(tuple.get_id()));
        return true;
    }
    db.close();
    return false;

}
```

calling methods from service

```
                //doing 5 times    
                dbHandler dbH = new dbHandler(this, null, null, 1);
                if (dbH.checkNotAvailable(n))
                    dbH.add_n(n);
```

Log.d Output repeated on every service call

```
        D/NO ENTRY: 0
        D/ After Adding Data...: Name 1
        D/NO ENTRY: 1
        D/ After Adding Data...: Name 2
        D/NO ENTRY: 2
        D/ After Adding Data...: Name 3
        D/NO ENTRY: 3
        D/ After Adding Data...: Name 4
        D/NO ENTRY: 4
        D/ After Adding Data...: Name 5
```

Comment: Are you clearing the data(i.e. data from the Applications in your device) every time you restart the service in any part of your app?

Comment: No .That is the only instance of using the dbHandler object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, I was passing null to the dbhandler  constructor and didn't specify the name of database which might have resulted in forming temporary database which cleared on service stops.